# Render component with conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 List, groupQuestionList and questionList. I'm trying to render using conditional like the following:

```
{groupQuestionList
    .map((group, index) => (
        <QuestionGroupHeader key={index} group={group} />,
        questionList
            .map((question, index2) => (
                question.group === group.id 
                ? <QuestionRow key = {index2} question={question} /> 
                : null))
     ))
}
```

Below is the result I hope for

```
Group A
    Question 1
    Question 2
Group B
    Question 3
    Question 4
```

Somehow, only questions are rendered, i lost all the Group. I've tried something else like `<QuestionRow />` inside `<QuestionGroupHeader />`, but the format isn't suitable.

Can anyone kindly explain where I'm wrong, and any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: can you show the data structure of your groupQuestionList?

Comment: Shouldn't your questions be contained in your groups ?

Comment: groupQuestionList has "id" and "name", questionList has "group"-id and others

Comment: @Treycos yeah, it should be, and i've tried it, but the result isn't what i want. It did what i wanted in this case, but the format of my table is completely collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way yo return from the first `map`.

You are using the implicit return and you have wrapped the two things you wanted in  `()` separated by a `,`. This syntax means that the last thing is what will be returned from that expression as it is the last thing evaluated.

You most likely wanted to use `[]` which will return an array with both items.

```
.map((group, index) => [
    <QuestionGroupHeader key={index} group={group} />,
    questionList
        .map((question, index2) => (
            question.group === group.id 
            ? <QuestionRow key = {index2} question={question} /> 
            : null))
 ])
```

Comment: Thanks Petrioli, it worked. I still have many things to learn

Answer (score 1):

According to the code provided, the following syntax would be correct :

```
{
    groupQuestionList.map((group, index) => 
        <div>
            <QuestionGroupHeader key={index} group={group} />
            {questionList.map((question, index2) => question.group === group.id && <QuestionRow key={index2} question={question} />)}
        </div>
}
```

You can even replace the `div` with fragments if your React version is up to date.

Using the inline `if` : `&&` allow you to also remove your ternary condition.

I would also recommend storing an id or anything unique in both your arrays to use them as keys and get better performance.

Comment: Thanks Treycos, it solved my problem about how to render both components. By the way, it leads to my old trouble: Table format is collapsed.